# Site & List User Permissions

Tags: permissions

I am using a custom list where the end user has to edit the form to enter in information. Because of this, I have to give them edit permissions to the list which I can do in the List Settings.

However, they do not need editing permissions to the entire site. Can I give only "Read" permissions to the site and then give unique permissions of Edit-View to the list?

Answer (score 2):

It is all about **Keys** and **Access**

---

**A SharePoint Farm is like a Business Park:**

[image]

---

**then Site Collections are Buildings:**

As [Site Collection Owner](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Permissions-for-site-collection-administrators-f7f82b3e-7ef3-4938-a49b-9504de3b6c2a) you have a **MasterKey** to all information in this building.
[Permission Profiles](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/understanding_sharepoint_and_office365_permission_levels) can be centrally managed, *but **alas** most SharePoint 'consultants' don't use its power

[image]

---

**Subsites (Webs) are Rooms:**

[image]

---

**Document Libraries/Lists are Cabinets:**

[image]

---

**Documents-Sets/Folders are File Suspension Holders:**

[DocumentSets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Document-Sets-c49c246d-31f1-4bfe-afe2-e26698b47e05) are available since SP2010 and underestimated by many
(*and most often completely unknown*)

[image]

---

**and Documents/List Items are Files:**
with metadata

[image]

---

## Permissions to all

On each of the above you can have different locks(permission profiles) (each can have 33 types of SharePoint [permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx) to be precise).
**And you have to check each one to see what permissions you have**

Either by hand or a Powershell script.
Search can give you a clue where you have Read rights (but you can have *Write* rights without *Read* rights..)

## And then the metaphore goes wrong...

**OMG!** In the digital world you can have access to  a File and **NOT** have access to the File-Holder or Cabinet or Room or Building or Business Park.

Ah... [Governance](http://blog.epcgroup.net/security-governance-sharepoint-bestpractices-sharepoint2013-office365-epcgroup/)

*Most will try and sell you 3rd party tools to manage this all... but if your foundation is crap, no tool can fix it for you*

Just like an architect plans every detail of a building,
good [Permissions planning for sites and content in SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262939.aspx) is key

iSPT

Comment: Thanks. I tested some unique permissions with my site yesterday as I described above and it didn't work out like I thought. That's why I posted the question. I was pretty sure it was possible, but just wanted to double check.

Comment: This is a great example.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.  Go to List settings, permissions for this list, and break the permissions inheritance.  Then you can apply the permissions specifically to that list. [This page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-and-manage-permissions-for-a-SharePoint-list-or-library-02D770F3-59EB-4910-A608-5F84CC297782?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) has step by step instructions for SharePoint Online/2016/2013/2010/2007 with pictures.